# Sorting a list of lists by item frequency in Python 2.3

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list, with sub-lists of items like this.

```
mylist = [
['ITEM A', 'YES', 'NO', 'YES', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO'],
['ITEM B', 'YES', 'NO', 'YES', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'MAYBE'],
['ITEM C', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'MAYBE', 'NO', 'MAYBE']
]
```

Now I want to sort the sub lists on this condition — the more each row (i.e. sub list) has the items `'YES'` and `'MAYBE'`, the higher it moves up. The more `'NO'`s each row has, the lower it moves in the sorting list.

The ideal result would be —

```
mylist = [
['ITEM C', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'MAYBE', 'NO', 'MAYBE'],
['ITEM B', 'YES', 'NO', 'YES', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'MAYBE'],
['ITEM A', 'YES', 'NO', 'YES', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO']
]
#Item C has 4 'YES' and 2 'MAYBE'
#Item B has 3 'YES' and 1 'MAYBE'
#Item C has 3 'YES'
```

Sadly, I'm stuck on **Python 2.3**, and need to find out the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: @Nima sometimes people as stuck with older versions at work (and lack of / resistance to upgrades by the people making decisions). I worked at a place like that, so OP may not have a choice.

Comment: @Levon Well said. I'm working on a legacy system, developing in 2.3 currently. It blows, but it's necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General solution: use `list.sort` with a key function returning a tuple:

```
mylist.sort(key=lambda sl: (sl.count('YES') + sl.count('MAYBE'), -sl.count('NO')), reverse=True)
```

`key` and `reverse` were added in Python 2.4, so you'll have to do it manually:

```
key = lambda sl: (sl.count('YES') + sl.count('MAYBE'), -sl.count('NO'))
mylist.sort(lambda p, q: -cmp(key(p), key(q)))
```

If `key` is slow it's best to use a solution that computes the `key` function on each item only once (a so-called "[Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)"). Note that >=Python 2.4 perform this optimisation (or similar) already:

```
def key_sort(seq, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False):
    if key is not None:
        transform = [(key(x), i, x) for i, x in enumerate(seq)]
        transform.sort(None if cmp is None else lambda (k, _, _), (l, _, _): cmp(k, l))
        seq[:] = [x for _, _, x in transform]
    else:
        seq.sort(cmp)
    if reverse:
        seq.reverse()
```

Comment: +1, but the OP may need to play around with `key`. The main idea is that it should return a tuple. I'd suggest something like `(sl.count('YES'), sl.count('MAYBE'), -sl.count('NO'))` in case `'YES'` is any better than `'MAYBE'`.

Comment: I think sorting [works a bit differently](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3/lib/typesseq-mutable.html) in python2.3

Comment: Add some weights for the YES and MAYBE. Say, (100, 10, -100) for (YES, MAYBE, NO)

Comment: @Ribtoks that works if 10 MAYBE count as 1 YES; the tuple approach is necessary if successes and failures are to be considered separately.

Answer (score 3):

To sort by a key in Python 2.3 or lower, you *could* use the `cmp` parameter. But sometimes `key` style sorting is easier to read; and in any case, it does less work, since `cmp` will be called O(n log n) times, while the `key` function will be called only O(n) times.

With that in mind, here's a way to reproduce the behavior of the `key` parameter in later versions of Python. It uses the decorate-sort-undecorate idiom, a.k.a. the [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform). This won't be quite as space efficient because it makes copies, but for large lists, it is likely to be more time efficient. I've named this `sorted` because it roughly reproduces the `sorted` function added in 2.4; check the python version and conditionally import this so that you don't smash the built-in `sorted` in newer versions -- or just rename it.

```
def sorted(seq, key=lambda x: None, reverse=False):
    seq = [(key(x), i, x) for i, x in enumerate(seq)]
    seq.sort()
    if reverse:
        seq.reverse()
    return [x for k, i, x in seq]
```

Note that `enumerate` is only necessary if you care about having a stable sort on unequal values with equal keys; it slows down the function by a hair. Tested on your data:

```
>>> key=lambda x: (x.count('YES'), x.count('MAYBE'), x.count('NO'))
>>> my_sorted(mylist, key=key, reverse=True)
[['ITEM C', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'MAYBE', 'NO', 'MAYBE'], 
 ['ITEM B', 'YES', 'NO', 'YES', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'MAYBE'], 
 ['ITEM A', 'YES', 'NO', 'YES', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO']]
```

You might also consider using a dictionary to do your counting; that way, only one pass is required. However, `count` is sufficiently optimized that three passes are still faster than one Python `for` loop, at least on my machine. So only use this if you need to count lots of values. I'll leave this here for posterity:

```
def my_key(inner_list):
    counts = {'YES':0, 'MAYBE':0, 'NO':0}
    for i in inner_list:
        if i in counts:
            counts[i] += 1
    return (counts['YES'], counts['MAYBE'], counts['NO'])
```

---

I did some testing; apologies for the long post. The below is only for the curious and inquisitive.

My tests indicate that on the smaller list, decorate, sort, undecorate is *already faster* than using the built-in sort + `cmp`. On a bigger list, the difference becomes more dramatic. Definitions:

```
def key_count(x):
    return (x.count('YES'), x.count('MAYBE'), x.count('NO'))

def key_dict(inner_list):
    counts = {'YES':0, 'MAYBE':0, 'NO':0}
    for i in inner_list:
        if i in counts:
            counts[i] += 1
    return (counts['YES'], counts['MAYBE'], counts['NO'])

def decorate_sort(seq, key=lambda x: None, reverse=False):
    seq = [(key(x), i, x) for i, x in enumerate(seq)]
    seq.sort()
    if reverse:
        seq.reverse()
    return [x for k, i, x in seq]

def builtin_sort(seq, key, reverse=False):
    seq.sort(lambda p, q: cmp(key(p), key(q)))
    if reverse:
        seq.reverse()
```

Tests:

```
>>> mylist = [
... ['ITEM A', 'YES', 'NO', 'YES', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO'],
... ['ITEM B', 'YES', 'NO', 'YES', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'MAYBE'],
... ['ITEM C', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'MAYBE', 'NO', 'MAYBE']
... ]
>>> %timeit decorate_sort(mylist, key=key_count, reverse=True)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.03 us per loop
>>> %timeit builtin_sort(mylist, key=key_count, reverse=True)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.28 us per loop
```

The built-in version is already slower! The less-generalized version `mylist.sort(lambda p, q: -cmp(key(p), key(q)))` is a better by a hair for a short list, because of the addition of `enumerate` to `decorate_sort`; without it, `decorate_sort` is faster (4.28 us per loop in my previous test):

```
>>> %timeit mylist.sort(lambda p, q: -cmp(key_count(p), key_count(q)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.74 us per loop
```

Using `key_dict` is a mistake in this case, though:

```
>>> %timeit decorate_sort(mylist, key=key_dict, reverse=True)
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.97 us per loop
>>> %timeit builtin_sort(mylist, key=key_dict, reverse=True)
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.4 us per loop
```

Testing it on a larger list, basically the same results hold:

```
>>> import random
>>> mylist = [[random.choice(('YES', 'MAYBE', 'NO')) for _ in range(1000)] 
              for _ in range(100)]
>>> %timeit decorate_sort(mylist, key=key_count, reverse=True)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.93 ms per loop
>>> %timeit builtin_sort(mylist, key=key_count, reverse=True)
10 loops, best of 3: 34.5 ms per loop
```

The less generalized version is now slower than `decorate_sort`.

```
>>> %timeit mylist.sort(lambda p, q: -cmp(key_count(p), key_count(q)))
100 loops, best of 3: 13.5 ms per loop
```

And `key_dict` is still slower. (But faster than `builtin_sort`!)

```
>>> %timeit decorate_sort(mylist, key=key_dict, reverse=True)
10 loops, best of 3: 20.4 ms per loop
>>> %timeit builtin_sort(mylist, key=key_dict, reverse=True)
10 loops, best of 3: 103 ms per loop
```

So the upshot is that the Schwartzian Transform provides a solution that is both faster *and* more generalized -- a rare and wonderful combination.

Comment: Thanks for the fantastically detailed analysis. I will check all of these. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately, your Schwartzian transform can break the stable sort guarantee (if `key(x)` and `key(y)` compare equal but `x` and `y` compare unequal).  An easy fix is to store the index in the transformed tuple: `seq = [(key(x), i, x) for i, x in enumerate(seq)]`

Comment: Also, it doesn't allow providing *both* a `key` and `cmp` - if you'd ever want to!  I've extended your solution with both fixes in my answer.

Comment: @ecatmur, yeah, I kind of left `cmp` out on purpose. If you want to use `cmp`, just use the built-in version, which will be faster than anything coded in Python. Also, I've seen people use both `cmp` and `key` before, and I thought it was a bad idea. I prefer the Python 3 way of doing things in this case. Still, thanks for reminding me about sort stability.